# In my ~/Library folder there is Caches folder. Can this be emptied?

Tags: storage, macos

My ~/Library folder has gotten very large. Inside this ~/Library folder is a folder name Caches. This folder 5.5 GB. Can this Caches folder be trashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Enjoy this sweet release.

- [Is it safe to delete ~/Library/Caches?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118941/is-it-safe-to-delete-library-caches)

*and savor the sensation when the next program to write to that folder finds the folder misssing.* Usually the slow down to rebuild all the cached files isn’t worse than [whatever you are experiencing now](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360890/disk-drive-about-full-library-folder-has-over-100-gb) to cause you to want to purge.

Comment: Thanks, i just wanted to empty the caches folder.  I appreciate your answer.  I can sure use that 5 GB.

Comment: I hope the humor on the empty folder was apparent, I’ve not seen anything break horribly as a result of even a ham fisted attempt to delete the entire folder itself. @jmh

Comment: Yes, the humor was apparent and it made me laugh.

Comment: @jmh Please close the question :)